# SpriteKit Node.intersectsNode() method not detecting intersections under strange conditions

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building somewhat of a really awful platform game and I'm trying to detect if parts of a node are in the same location as parts of another node. I'll use method:

```
func intersectingNode(node: SKNode) -> SKNode?{
   for floorObject in floorObjects{ // floorObjects is of type [SKNode]
        if floorObject.intersectsNode(node){
            return floorObject
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I should point out at this time that the anchor points of all nodes involved here are at (0.5, 0.5). The anchor point of the main SKScene is at the bottom left corner of the window.

This method is supposed to return the object in the `floorObjects` array that `node` is intersecting with, and if it's not intersecting with any object in the `floorObjects` array, the method will return no node. But my problem is this: the method is not returning any node if the x position of `node` is less than the x position of `floorObject` and the y position of `node` is greater than the y position of `floorObject`. Now since the anchor point on all nodes are at (0.5, 0.5), some of that area is on top of the top-left quarter of `floorObject`.

If I change the third line to this:

```
if node.intersectsNode(floorObject){
```

the x position of `floorObject` would be less than the x position of `node` and the y position of `floorObject` would be greater than the y position of `node`.

So how can I make sure that the method above is always returning a node if anywhere in the frame of one node is somewhere inside of the frame of another node?

Comment: I suggest you add `println (floorObject.frame)` to your loop to determine the positions/sizes of the `floorObjects`.

Comment: if the nodes are `SKNode`s then they won't have frames.

Comment: @Okapi an `SKNode` does have a frame property with `size == (0,0)`. I suspected that was the issue causing the unexpected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the `frame`s directly, which ought to give you what you need:

```
if node.frame.intersects(floorObject.frame) {
    return floorObject
}
```

[Link to Playground](http://d.pr/f/1hnd0/WxwgGWM2)